# WPF update UI Control asynchronously with a delay?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

```
public void TextChangedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox changedTextBox = sender as TextBox;
            List<TextBox> textBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
            //gets Grid that contains all the textboxes
            var parentGrid = VisualHierarchyHelper.FindParent<Grid>(changedTextBox);
            var mainGrid = VisualHierarchyHelper.FindParent<Grid>(parentGrid);
            //ALL 81 textboxes
            var textBoxChildren = VisualHierarchyHelper.FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(mainGrid).ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < textBoxChildren.Count; i++)
            {
                SendWithDelay(textBoxChildren[i]);
            }
        }

        async Task SendWithDelay(TextBox txt)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            txt.Background = Brushes.Red;
        }
```

I want 81 grids to get a red background 1 by one, now it just waits a bit and updates everything at once.

Any suggestions?

Note: This code is runnable but it does complain about `SendWithDelay(textBoxChildren[i]);` not being awaited, if I change this and also change `void` to `async Task` it says `Error   CS0407 'Task EventHandling.TextChangedEvent(object, EventArgs)' has the wrong return type`.

**EDIT**

This is what I have now:

```
public void TextChangedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox changedTextBox = sender as TextBox;
            List<TextBox> textBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
            //gets Grid that contains all the textboxes
            var parentGrid = VisualHierarchyHelper.FindParent<Grid>(changedTextBox);
            var mainGrid = VisualHierarchyHelper.FindParent<Grid>(parentGrid);
            //ALL 81 textboxes
            var textBoxChildren = VisualHierarchyHelper.FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(mainGrid).ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < textBoxChildren.Count; i++)
            {
                x SendWithDelay(textBoxChildren[i]);
            }
        }

        async void SendWithDelay(TextBox txt)
        {
            txt.Background = Brushes.Red;   
            x await Task.Delay(500);
        }
```

The breakpoints(x) just alternate between each other. Then when they're done everything gets red.

Comment: try `await SendWithDelay(textBoxChildren[i]);`

Comment: I tried this already, it now says: Task EventHandling.TextChangedEvent(object, EventArgs)' has the wrong return type, which I don't understand as this event is a void right? It has Task and not Task<>

Comment: make `public async void TextChanged`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*1 second Delay*

```
async Task LongRunningProcess()
{

    await Task.Delay(1000);

}
```

*In your loop*

```
public async void TextChangedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < textBoxChildren.Count; i++)
  {
     txt.Background = Brushes.Red;
     await Task.Run(() => LongRunningProcess());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make make `TextChangedEvent` async:

`public async void TextChangedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e) {`

And await the call to `SendWithDelay`:

`await SendWithDelay(textBoxChildren[i]);`

It'll get rid of all the warnings you're getting, but it seems like you want `SendWithDelay` to be "Fire and forget", this way you can change `SendWithDelay` to `async void` instead of `async Task`:

`async Task SendWithDelay(TextBox txt) {`

And **not** await every call to it:

`SendWithDelay(textBoxChildren[i]);`

Comment: Thanks, the warnings are now indeed gone. However, it waits a second and then **all** textboxes get a red background.

Comment: @Mayfair follow the second two instructions